# Turn off line numbering in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e, line-numbering

I have the following preamble for `algorithm2e`:

```
   \usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
```

I have many algorithms, in on of the algorithm as follows:

```
 \begin{algorithm}[t!]
    \centering
    nonumbering
    \caption{CAmple}\label{algoCPOR}
    \end{algorithm}
```

I do not want the line **nonumbering** (only that line) to be numbered, how should I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your use-case, you can either use `\LinesNotNumbered` or `\LinesNumberedHidden` to temporarily remove lines numbers in an `algorithm`. Under the latter, `\ShowLn` prints the line number for that specific line (if you wish to intermix showing/not):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\begin{document}

{\LinesNumberedHidden
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \centering
  nonumbering
  \caption{CAmple1}\label{algoCPOR1}
\end{algorithm}}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \centering
  nonumbering
  \caption{CAmple2}\label{algoCPOR2}
\end{algorithm}

\LinesNumberedHidden
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \centering\ShowLn
  nonumbering
  \caption{CAmple3}\label{algoCPOR3}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```